# Do professional 3D modelers use human bases?

Tags: 3d

I tried to find an answer on google and didn't get much. 
I wanna know, do professional 3D modelers (Specifically in the video game industry) work off generic base human models to make their own? Or do they make their entire body and face models from scratch?

Bases like these for example:
[image]

Comment: Depends on the person, depends on the project, depends on the team. I'm sure that there have been cases where bases like these have been used, and projects where they haven't. It is not possible to generalize this. Is there a specific problem you're facing?

Comment: ...if you can think of a way that it could be done, somebody is doing it that way. About just about everything...

Comment: No, no problem just curious.

Answer (score 2):

They do whatever it takes to get the job done in the time allotted to the project.  If that means working off of reference art or using existing assets that they have the legal right to use (licensing, etc.) then that's what they do.

The kinds of schedules we pulled in game development pretty much required everyone to cut whatever corners necessary to meet deadline.